# Laravel - Redirect to a route POST

Tags: laravel, validation, redirect

I've tried to redirect my POSTform if validator fails, but it does not work because it's not a GET route.
I've a first page for choose a product, post to second page for add one model to the product.
I'want to redirect to the 2nd page if validator fails.

**Validation**:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('admin/modele/create')
             ->withErrors($validator)
             ->withInput();
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('modele/select/product', 'ModeleController@selectProduct')->name('modele.selectProduct'); //get page for select product
Route::post('modele/selected/product', 'ModeleController@selectedProduct')->name('modele.selectedProduct');  //the product is selected, send it to form page
Route::post('modele/create/product/{produit}', 'ModeleController@storea')->name('modele.storea'); //is a store custom
```

**Controller:**

```
public function selectProduct() 
    {
        //
          $lesProduits = Produit::pluck('nom', 'id');
          return view('admin/modele/select', compact('lesProduits'));

    }

     public function selectedProduct(Request $request) 
    {
        //

            $unProduit = $request->get('produit');
            $id = ($request->get('produit'));

            $unProduit = Produit::where('id', $id)->pluck('nom', 'id');
            $uneCategorie = Produit::find($id)->categorie;
            $produit = Produit::find($id);
           //dd($uneCategorie)   ;
            //$categorie = $unProduit->categorie->id;

            return view('admin/modele/create', compact('unProduit', 'uneCategorie', 'produit'));

    }
public function storea(Request $request, $produit_id)
    {
        //
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'ref' => 'required|max:255',
            'prixHT' => 'required|max:9|numeric',
            'prixHTpromo' => 'max:9|numeric',
            'quantite' => 'required|numeric|max:255',
            't1' => 'max:255',
             't2' => 'max:255',
             't3' => 'max:255',
             't4' => 'max:255',
             't5' => 'max:255',
             't6' => 'max:255',
             't7' => 'max:255',
             't8' => 'max:255',
             't9' => 'max:255',
             't10' => 'max:255',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
             return redirect('admin/modele/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
        else
        {        
            $unModele = New Modele();
            $unModele->produit_id = $produit_id;
            $unModele->ref = $request->get('ref');
            $unModele->prixHT = $request->get('prixHT');
            if ($request->get('prixHTpromo') != null)
            {
               $unModele->prixHPromoHT = $request->get('prixHTpromo');   
            }      
            $unModele->quantiteDebut = $request->get('quantite');
            for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++)
            {
                $name = 't'.$i;
                $nameDB = 'info'.$i;
                if ($request->get($name) != null)
                {
                    $unModele->$nameDB = $request->get($name);
                }
            }
            // photo 0,1             
            if($request->file('image') != null) // && $uneActualite->url != null)
            {
                //image code here
            }
            else
            {
                $unModele->image=null;
            }
          /////////////////////////
            $unModele->save();
            $request->session()->flash("success","Modèle ajouté.");
            return redirect(route('modele.index'));        
        }


    }
```

**Select page:**

```
     {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'modele.selectedProduct')) !!}


                            <div class="form-group">
                 {!! Form::label('produit', 'Produit') !!}
                 {!! Form::select('produit',$lesProduits, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                            </div>
                @if ($errors->has('produit'))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->get('produit') as $message) 
                                        <li>{{$message}}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            @endif




                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Create model page:**

```
                    {!! Form::open(array('route' => ['modele.storea', $produit->id],'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}


                    <div class="form-group">
         {!! Form::label('produit', 'Produit') !!}
         {!! Form::select('produit', $unProduit, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                    </div>
        @if ($errors->has('produit'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->get('produit') as $message) 
                                <li>{{$message}}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('ref', 'Réference') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('ref', null,array('maxlength' => 255, 'class'=>'form-control' )) !!}                        
                    </div>                        
                    @if ($errors->has('ref'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->get('ref') as $message) 
                        <li>{{$message}}</li>
                    @endforeach
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    @endif
@for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++)
                                <?php $item_name = 't' . $i; ?>

                                @if ($uneCategorie->$item_name != null)
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                         {!! Form::label($item_name, $uneCategorie->$item_name) !!}
                                         {!! Form::text($item_name, null,array('maxlength' => 255, 'class'=>'form-control' )) !!}                        
                                         </div>                        
                                         @if ($errors->has('{{$item_name }}'))
                                         <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                             <ul>
                                         @foreach ($errors->get('{{$item_name }}') as $message) 
                                             <li>{{$message}}</li>
                                         @endforeach
                                         </ul>
                                         </div>
                                         @endif
                                    </div>
                                @endif                                            
                            @endfor
```

Comment: Please let us know the page conventions you have there, this is the routes page? You should run validations in the controller.

Comment: Are you checking validation in routes page?

Comment: You should give us more information.

Comment: the validator is in modelController storea. I've use it many times but never for redirect a POST page. What do you want as information

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had a similar issue and here is my solution, rewritten to match topic owners post:

Routes:

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'modele/selected/product', 'ModeleController@selectedProduct')->name('modele.selectedProduct');
```

Controller

```
$unProduit = $request->get('produit')??session('_old_input')['produit_id'];
```

Create Model Page

```
{{ Form::hidden('produit_id', $unProduit->id) }}
```

This works at least with Laravel 5.6 and PHP 7+

Answer (score 0):

you have to make get request  .. cannot make request to post in that case

Comment: How I do then ?